# Why does mobx-react observer break react-router-dom navlink active class?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, mobx, mobx-react, react-router-dom

When using `mobx-react`'s `observer` the application of an *active class* on `react-router`'s `NavLink` component is broken.

Setup that produces problem:

using create react app

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "routertest",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "mobx": "^3.1.9",
    "mobx-react": "^4.1.8",
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "0.9.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import Nav from './Nav';
import './App.css';

const Home = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>Home</h2>
  </div>
)

const About = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>About</h2>
  </div>
)
const Topics = ({ match }) => (
  <div>
    <h2>Topics</h2>
  </div>
)



class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="App">
          <Nav />
          <hr />
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/about" component={About} />
          <Route path="/topics" component={Topics} />
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter >
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Nav.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import { observer } from 'mobx-react';

const Nav = observer (class Nav extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <ul>
                <li><NavLink exact to="/" activeClassName="active">Home</NavLink></li>
                <li><NavLink to="/about" activeClassName="active">About</NavLink></li>
                <li><NavLink to="/topics" activeClassName="active">Topics</NavLink></li>
            </ul>
        );
    }
})

export default Nav;
```

This is a simplified display of the problem. My use case involves actually using a `mobx store` to create the `NavLink`'s and also using decorators. Looking for *why* the observer wrapper stops `react-router-dom` from applying the active class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just need to stack my class wrappers/decorators. 
This example was using the base createReactApp so there are no decorators, but the actual use case I had was using typescript fork of createReactApp and did support decorators.

My problem was solved by stacking the decorators on classes so that the `context` from react router and mobx was passed down.

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/withRouter.md

example:

```
@withRouter
@inject('store')
@observer
export class MyComponent extends React.Component{
...
}
```

Comment: Note that this strictly speaking does not require decorators, `class _MyComponent {}; export const MyComponent = withRouter(inject('store')(observer(_MyComponent)))` achieves the same